# Unix - Surround First Column of CSV with double quotes

Tags: unix, sed, csv, awk

I have data in the following format -

```
4,"abc"
8,"def"
9,"ghi"
```

I want to surround the value of the first column by double quotes.

```
"4","abc"
"8","def"
"9","ghi"
```

How do I do that ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A very simple substitution is:

```
awk -F, '{sub($1, "\"&\""); print}' tmp.csv
```

(Thanks *evilsoup*).

The option -F, tells awk that the field delimiter is the comma, the argument of sub(stitution)
tells awk to replace the first field with itself (&), preceded and followed by ".

Comment: [Useless use of `cat`](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html), but +1 anyway.

Comment: Right. Should be awk -F, '{sub($1, "\"&\""); print}' tmp.csv. TY

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/[^,]*/"&"/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a quick and dirty way (there will be better ways):

```
sed -e 's/"//g' -e 's/^\|$/"/g' -e 's/,/","/g' file.csv
```

The first `s/"//g` removes all `"`.
Then `s/^\|$/"/g` adds a `"` at the beginning and end of the line.
And last `s/,/","/g` replaces all `,` by `","`.

Of course this **only** works if you don't have `"` and `,` **in** your fields.